# Why this language returns the number 3 when I'm expecting the cause of the error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using a try except and when it excepts I print the error, then it shows error as 3

I tryed to check it out in web but I have never seen something like that and google always thinks I'm searching something like python 3 errors

```
try:
    #code
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It results in the numbem 3 printed in console

I expect to see the actual error or at least know why this error is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module to get the traceback from the exception.

The linked documentation has a number of different ways to print out a traceback, but this is sufficient if you want to print a traceback like an uncaught exception to stdout without terminating the program:

```
import sys, traceback

try:
  i = 10 / 0 # throws a ZeroDivisionError
except Exception:
  exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
  # exc_type below is ignored on 3.5 and later
  traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback,
                            limit=2, file=sys.stdout)
  print("Still running!")
```

This gives the following output in stdout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    i = 10 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Still running!
```